# WordPress 3.0 custom post type with upload

Tags: wordpress, upload

Is there a way to insert one (or more) upload field on a custom post type edition page?

I don't want to use the midia gallery with all the fields and stuff.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? What don't you like about the media gallery?

Comment: I need a upload field on the page because I want to make it simple, the user don't have to full fill the media gallery form, attach the attachment... I just want to upload the file and have the namefile on somewhere, not necessarily a post (on the posts table)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a fairly basic example, but it should get you on your way;

```
function my_upload_field()
{
    echo '<input type="file" name="my_upload_field" />';
}
add_action('init', create_function('',
    'add_meta_box("my_upload_field", "Upload File", "my_upload_field", "post");'));

function handle_upload_field($post_ID, $post)
{
    if (!empty($_FILES['my_upload_field']['name'])) {
        $upload = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['my_upload_field']);
        if (!isset($upload['error'])) {
            // no errors, do what you like
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'handle_upload_field', 10, 2);
```

Check out the codex on [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), and take a look at `wp_handle_upload()` (line 239 `wp-admin/includes/file.php` as of 3.0) for more information.

Comment: Any idea why, when I use your code, it tells me that add_meta_box is not defined. Is init too early to use this in my functions.php file?

Comment: Do you happen to know how to attach the uploaded file to post? I found `wp_insert_attachment()`, but is it possible to also handle re-uploading like media library does? (When you re-upload image it actually doesn't make two copies to folder)

Comment: Not sure what you mean - you can attach an attachment to a post by setting `post_parent` to the corresponding ID.